# Should I edit question to format equation linked as image in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, editing, mathjax, formatting

I often come across questions where the author uses a linked image of an equation instead of typesetting it as MathJax. Should I edit the question to typeset the equation in MathJax, comment to let the author know that the site supports MathJax?

I find equations linked as images on this site distasteful, but are they actually against policy? I didn't find any specific proscription in the help center.

Comment: Yes, eventually Google will improve it's indexing of non standard text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should edit and/or leave a comment in these cases because

- Images are fixed size and will display poorly in small browser windows, particularly on phones.
- MathJax is searchable, although the search functionality is usually not all that useful.
- MathJax provides a uniform style for typesetting, while the typesetting in images can vary wildly depending on the source.

Comment: Is there a reason apart from preferred style? For example are typeset equations searchable?

Comment: @renegade_anteater Yes, they are searchable (but search doesn't work all that well, tbh). Also, I think it's less about preferred style and more about *uniform* style. The typesetting in images varies wildly depending on where the images are taken from, but MathJax provides a uniform style everyone can use.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Uniformity is really helpful on mobile browsers especially I find.  You never quite know when an image will load to take up a full page, or load at really low resolution so it can't be read.